# Websocket support on JBoss 6

Tags: websocket, jboss6.x

I have been exploring options to provide websocket support on JBoss 6. WebSocket was added in Java EE 7 so JBoss 6 doesn't have native support for it.

I explored other options to get websocket support on JBoss 6. One of the commonly suggested approaches is to use Atmosphere library. But found that Atmosphere on JBoss 6 falls back to long polling (doesn't support websockets). Here is the reference,[link](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Supported-WebServers-and-Browsers). I need websocket support and no alternatives.

My investigation so far suggests that, websockets support requires changes in transport protocol mechanism. So we can't get native support for it on JBoss 6 even by adding external jars/libraries.

Any suggestion/opinion ??

Comment: Websockets support on boss starts from EAP 6.3, http://blog.arungupta.me/websocket-jboss-eap-6-3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find any reference for websocket support on JBoss 6. JBoss supports it from EAP 6.3

So going ahead with HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of JBoss are you using? 6.2+ works with https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Installing-JBoss-WebSocket-Support

Comment: I need it for version 6, also atmosphere is not an option for me.